# Spring Boot long running asynchronous job

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am new to SpringBoot and I have a design and development question w.r.t SpringBoot.

Here is my question :

I would have to expose an end point for a long running asynchronous job.

Here is what i am thinking :

1. Expose the end-point which will return a 202 accepted, if its a valid POST request. Also return a task-id w.r.t to this job.
2. Expose another end-point which allows end user to query this task for a success or failure status.

Could you please let me know if this approach is good? Could you please let me know if there are better approaches to solve this?

P.S. if anyone could point me to sample examples that i could look at and use it for my development, that would also be helpful.